# Android Google Analytics - adding to which xml?

Tags: android, google-analytics-api

I was instructed to add the following to some file but not sure which one, please help me.

Mark application entry – Manifest

```
Add Analytics as application name on Manifest entry as below :

<application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       android:name=".Analytics">
```

but my current project manifest already have the following:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

What should it become now?

Comment: It states to add `application name` as `.Analytics` which is not in your `application` tag. I have never worked with analytics integration so I don't know if its necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This means you have `Analytics`  application class in your app

```
android:name=".Analytics"
```

will consider as your application base class.

for more info please refer this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SDK v4, use the [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

The documentation is very straight forward so you shouldn't have any issues integrating it.

Comment: I am an extreme noob trying to learn... i am stuck on step 2, please help `2. Initialize Trackers`

Comment: Sure.. no worries.
In your application class (say `Abc extends Application`, add the code in your class `Abc`), create a public enum with the name `TrackerName`. Add the objects to it as shown in the step. Also create a hashmap `mTrackers` as indicated in the same step. Let me know when you re good with this.